# Converting sRGB D65 to CIELab D50

Tags: colors

I want to convert from sRGB D65 to CIELab D50. I'm aware of the Bruce Lindbloom functions and calculator but I just want to be sure if I am doing the calculations right.
Starting from a values of sR/100, sG/80, sB/20 and D65, would the following workflow be correct?
sRGB D65 -> XYZ -> Bradford Chromatic adaptation to D50 -> CIE Lab D50 = 34.99, 0.51, 31.35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something not working in the chromatic adaption part of your implementation.

Using [colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) and a manual conversion:

```py
>>> import colour
>>> import numpy as np
>>> RGB = np.array([100, 80, 20]) / 255
>>> D50 = colour.CCS_ILLUMINANTS['cie_2_1931']['D50']
>>> XYZ = colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(RGB, illuminant=D50)
>>> print(colour.XYZ_to_Lab(XYZ, illuminant=D50))
[ 35.31471609   3.63177851  37.28158403]
```

And with the Automatic Colour Conversion graph:

```py
>>> colour.convert(RGB, 'sRGB', 'CIE Lab', illuminant=D50) * 100
array([ 35.31471609,   3.63177851,  37.28158403]
```

And an alternative path that does not use the `colour.sRGB_to_XYZ` definition and seem to match yours:

```py
>>> colour.convert(RGB, 'Output-Referred RGB', 'CIE Lab', illuminant=D50, verbose={'mode': 'short'}) * 100
===============================================================================
*                                                                             *
*   [ Conversion Path ]                                                       *
*                                                                             *
*   "cctf_decoding" --> "RGB_to_XYZ" --> "XYZ_to_Lab"                         *
*                                                                             *
===============================================================================
array([ 34.99753019,   0.50577795,  31.35732344])
```

What is happening though here is that the conversion from *RGB* to *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values does not perform any chromatic adaptation between *D65* and *D50* because the `illuminant` argument is not matched by the `colour.RGB_to_XYZ` definition. The proper way to do it would be to specify `illuminant_RGB` for the *RGB* side although it defaults to *D65* and `illuminant_XYZ` for the *CIE XYZ* side:

```py
>>> colour.convert(RGB, 'Output-Referred RGB', 'CIE Lab', illuminant_XYZ=D50, illuminant=D50, verbose={'mode': 'short'}) * 100
===============================================================================
*                                                                             *
*   [ Conversion Path ]                                                       *
*                                                                             *
*   "cctf_decoding" --> "RGB_to_XYZ" --> "XYZ_to_Lab"                         *
*                                                                             *
===============================================================================
array([ 35.31471609,   3.63177851,  37.28158403])
```

Now we match the expected conversion result. Here is the verbose conversion so that you can check the intermediate values:

```py
>>> colour.convert(RGB, 'Output-Referred RGB', 'CIE Lab', RGB_to_XYZ={'illuminant_XYZ': D50}, XYZ_to_Lab={'illuminant': D50}, verbose={'mode': 'Extended'}) * 100
===================================================================================
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Conversion Path ]                                                           *
*                                                                                 *
*   "cctf_decoding" --> "RGB_to_XYZ" --> "XYZ_to_Lab"                             *
*                                                                                 *
===================================================================================
===================================================================================
*                                                                                 *
*   [ "cctf_decoding" ]                                                           *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Signature ]                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*   <Signature (value, function='sRGB', **kwargs)>                                *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Documentation ]                                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*   Decodes non-linear :math:`R'G'B'` values to linear :math:`RGB` values using   *
*   given decoding colour component transfer function (Decoding CCTF).            *
*                                                                                 *
*   Parameters                                                                    *
*   ----------                                                                    *
*   value : numeric or array_like                                                 *
*       Non-linear :math:`R'G'B'` values.                                         *
*   function : unicode, optional                                                  *
*       {:attr:`colour.CCTF_DECODINGS`},                                          *
*       Computation function.                                                     *
*                                                                                 *
*   Other Parameters                                                              *
*   ----------------                                                              *
*   \**kwargs : dict, optional                                                    *
*       Keywords arguments for the relevant decoding CCTF of the                  *
*       :attr:`colour.CCTF_DECODINGS` attribute collection.                       *
*                                                                                 *
*   Warnings                                                                      *
*   --------                                                                      *
*   For *ITU-R BT.2100*, only the electro-optical transfer functions              *
*   (EOTFs / EOCFs) are exposed by this definition, please refer to the           *
*   :func:`colour.oetf_inverse` definition for the inverse opto-electronic        *
*   transfer functions (OETF / OECF).                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*   Returns                                                                       *
*   -------                                                                       *
*   numeric or ndarray                                                            *
*       Linear :math:`RGB` values.                                                *
*                                                                                 *
*   Examples                                                                      *
*   --------                                                                      *
*   >>> cctf_decoding(0.391006842619746, function='PLog', log_reference=400)      *
*   ... # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                                      *
*   0.1...                                                                        *
*   >>> cctf_decoding(0.182011532850008, function='ST 2084', L_p=1000)            *
*   ... # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                                      *
*   0.1...                                                                        *
*   >>> cctf_decoding(  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                      *
*   ...     0.461356129500442, function='ITU-R BT.1886')                          *
*   0.1...                                                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Conversion Output ]                                                         *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ 0.12743768  0.08021982  0.00699541]                                         *
*                                                                                 *
===================================================================================
===================================================================================
*                                                                                 *
*   [ "RGB_to_XYZ" ]                                                              *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Signature ]                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*   <Signature (RGB, illuminant_RGB, illuminant_XYZ, matrix_RGB_to_XYZ,           *
*   chromatic_adaptation_transform='CAT02', cctf_decoding=None)>                  *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Filtered Arguments ]                                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   {'cctf_decoding': {'return': array([ 0.12743768,  0.08021982,                 *
*   0.00699541])},                                                                *
*    'illuminant_XYZ': array([ 0.3457,  0.3585])}                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Documentation ]                                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*   Converts given *RGB* colourspace array to *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values.       *
*                                                                                 *
*   Parameters                                                                    *
*   ----------                                                                    *
*   RGB : array_like                                                              *
*       *RGB* colourspace array.                                                  *
*   illuminant_RGB : array_like                                                   *
*       *CIE xy* chromaticity coordinates or *CIE xyY* colourspace array of the   *
*       *illuminant* for the input *RGB* colourspace array.                       *
*   illuminant_XYZ : array_like                                                   *
*       *CIE xy* chromaticity coordinates or *CIE xyY* colourspace array of the   *
*       *illuminant* for the output *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values.                 *
*   matrix_RGB_to_XYZ : array_like                                                *
*       Matrix converting the *RGB* colourspace array to *CIE XYZ* tristimulus    *
*       values, i.e. the *Normalised Primary Matrix* (NPM).                       *
*   chromatic_adaptation_transform : unicode, optional                            *
*       **{'CAT02', 'XYZ Scaling', 'Von Kries', 'Bradford', 'Sharp',              *
*       'Fairchild', 'CMCCAT97', 'CMCCAT2000', 'CAT02 Brill 2008',                *
*       'Bianco 2010', 'Bianco PC 2010', None}**,                                 *
*       *Chromatic adaptation* transform, if *None* no chromatic adaptation is    *
*       performed.                                                                *
*   cctf_decoding : object, optional                                              *
*       Decoding colour component transfer function (Decoding CCTF) or            *
*       electro-optical transfer function (EOTF / EOCF).                          *
*                                                                                 *
*   Returns                                                                       *
*   -------                                                                       *
*   ndarray                                                                       *
*       *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values.                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*   Notes                                                                         *
*   -----                                                                         *
*                                                                                 *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*   | **Domain**         | **Scale - Reference** | **Scale - 1** |                *
*   +====================+=======================+===============+                *
*   | ``RGB``            | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]        |                *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*   | ``illuminant_XYZ`` | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]        |                *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*   | ``illuminant_RGB`` | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]        |                *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*                                                                                 *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*   | **Range**          | **Scale - Reference** | **Scale - 1** |                *
*   +====================+=======================+===============+                *
*   | ``XYZ``            | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]        |                *
*   +--------------------+-----------------------+---------------+                *
*                                                                                 *
*   Examples                                                                      *
*   --------                                                                      *
*   >>> RGB = np.array([0.45595571, 0.03039702, 0.04087245])                      *
*   >>> illuminant_RGB = np.array([0.31270, 0.32900])                             *
*   >>> illuminant_XYZ = np.array([0.34570, 0.35850])                             *
*   >>> chromatic_adaptation_transform = 'Bradford'                               *
*   >>> matrix_RGB_to_XYZ = np.array(                                             *
*   ...     [[0.41240000, 0.35760000, 0.18050000],                                *
*   ...      [0.21260000, 0.71520000, 0.07220000],                                *
*   ...      [0.01930000, 0.11920000, 0.95050000]]                                *
*   ... )                                                                         *
*   >>> RGB_to_XYZ(RGB, illuminant_RGB, illuminant_XYZ, matrix_RGB_to_XYZ,        *
*   ...            chromatic_adaptation_transform)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS          *
*   array([ 0.2163881...,  0.1257    ,  0.0384749...])                            *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Conversion Output ]                                                         *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ 0.08765592  0.08656689  0.01383652]                                         *
*                                                                                 *
===================================================================================
===================================================================================
*                                                                                 *
*   [ "XYZ_to_Lab" ]                                                              *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Signature ]                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*   <Signature (XYZ, illuminant=array([ 0.3127,  0.329 ]))>                       *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Filtered Arguments ]                                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   {'illuminant': array([ 0.3457,  0.3585])}                                     *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Documentation ]                                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*   Converts from *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values to *CIE L\*a\*b\**                 *
*   colourspace.                                                                  *
*                                                                                 *
*   Parameters                                                                    *
*   ----------                                                                    *
*   XYZ : array_like                                                              *
*       *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values.                                             *
*   illuminant : array_like, optional                                             *
*       Reference *illuminant* *CIE xy* chromaticity coordinates or *CIE xyY*     *
*       colourspace array.                                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   Returns                                                                       *
*   -------                                                                       *
*   ndarray                                                                       *
*       *CIE L\*a\*b\** colourspace array.                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   Notes                                                                         *
*   -----                                                                         *
*                                                                                 *
*   +----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+                  *
*   | **Domain**     | **Scale - Reference** | **Scale - 1**   |                  *
*   +================+=======================+=================+                  *
*   | ``XYZ``        | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]          |                  *
*   +----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+                  *
*   | ``illuminant`` | [0, 1]                | [0, 1]          |                  *
*   +----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+                  *
*                                                                                 *
*   +----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+                  *
*   | **Range**      | **Scale - Reference** | **Scale - 1**   |                  *
*   +================+=======================+=================+                  *
*   | ``Lab``        | ``L`` : [0, 100]      | ``L`` : [0, 1]  |                  *
*   |                |                       |                 |                  *
*   |                | ``a`` : [-100, 100]   | ``a`` : [-1, 1] |                  *
*   |                |                       |                 |                  *
*   |                | ``b`` : [-100, 100]   | ``b`` : [-1, 1] |                  *
*   +----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+                  *
*                                                                                 *
*   References                                                                    *
*   ----------                                                                    *
*   :cite:`CIETC1-482004m`                                                        *
*                                                                                 *
*   Examples                                                                      *
*   --------                                                                      *
*   >>> import numpy as np                                                        *
*   >>> XYZ = np.array([0.20654008, 0.12197225, 0.05136952])                      *
*   >>> XYZ_to_Lab(XYZ)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                     *
*   array([ 41.5278752...,  52.6385830...,  26.9231792...])                       *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ Conversion Output ]                                                         *
*                                                                                 *
*   [ 0.35314716  0.03631779  0.37281584]                                         *
*                                                                                 *
===================================================================================
array([ 35.31471609,   3.63177851,  37.28158403])
```