# Python colour AttributeError: module 'colour' has no attribute 'CCS_ILLUMINANTS'

Tags: python-3.x, colors, rgb, cielab

I'm able to convert an RGB value to Lab using Colour and Numpy:

```
rgb = np.array([100, 80, 20]) / 255
xyz = colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(rgb)
lab = colour.XYZ_to_Lab(xyz)
print(lab) # 35, 4, 36
```

but when I want to use a specific white point, D50 like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756197/converting-srgb-d65-to-cielab-d50)

```
rgb = np.array([100, 80, 20]) / 255
D50 = colour.CCS_ILLUMINANTS['CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer']['D50']
xyz = colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(rgb, illuminant=D50)
print(colour.XYZ_to_Lab(xyz, illuminant=D50))
```

I get the error

```
D50 = colour.CCS_ILLUMINANTS['CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer']['D50']


File "D:\Python30\lib\site-packages\colour\__init__.py", line 325, in __getattr__
    return super(colour, self).__getattr__(attribute)
  File "D:\Python30\lib\site-packages\colour\utilities\deprecation.py", line 351, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._module, attribute)
AttributeError: module 'colour' has no attribute 'CCS_ILLUMINANTS'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the right package ?

Comment: I've tried py -3 -m pip install colour-science and py -3 -m pip install colour

Comment: Which version did you install? `colour.CCS_ILLUMINANTS` was introduced in version 0.3.16, you can try `colour.ILLUMINANTS` to check, if it is working, you are probably on an older version.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the colour files on Github, you can see that the correct path to CSS_ILLUMINANTS is something like this:

```
D50 = colour.colorimetry.datasets.CSS_ILLUMINANTS['CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer']['D50']
```

This way, it will work